# How do I get the bold round lower case x, like the one in the deeplearningbook for a vector?

Tags: vector

the image below comes from https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/linear_algebra.html

[image]

How do I get the x pointed out by the red arrow?

I've tried

```
$\boldsymbol{\mathit{x}}$

$\mathbf x$
```

both of them gave

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
$\bm{x}$
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

or

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
$\boldsymbol{x}$    
\end{document}
```

[image]

or try

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\boldsymbol{x}$    
\end{document}
```